# C# anonymous objects in "using" statements reliable?

Tags: c#, dispose, idisposable, using, using-statement

Imagine this snippet:

```
using System;



public class Report {
    static int Level=0;

    public static void WriteLine(string Message) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}",new String(' ',4*Level),Message);
    }

    public class Indent:IDisposable {
        public Indent()            { Report.WriteLine("{"); ++Level; }
        void IDisposable.Dispose() { --Level; Report.WriteLine("}"); }
    }
}



class Program {
    static void Main() {
        Report.WriteLine("Started");
        Report.WriteLine("Calling submethod");
        using(new Report.Indent()) {
            Report.WriteLine("Submethod started");
            using(new Report.Indent()) Report.WriteLine("Subsub, maybe?");
            Report.WriteLine("Submethod reporting everything is fine");
            Report.WriteLine("Submethod finished");
        }
        Report.WriteLine("Finished");
    }
}
```

Which produces result:

```
Started
Calling submethod
{
    Submethod started
    {
        Subsub, maybe?
    }
    Submethod reporting everything is fine
    Submethod finished
}
Finished
```

Inside I'm using `using(new Report.Indent())` instead of sticking to the only documented version I found, i.e. `using(Report.Indent r=new Report.Indent())`.

In my briefer version, however, can I be sure that `Dispose()` will always be called on those unnamed Indent objects, every time?

#### P.S.

```
// btw, I used word "anonymous" in the title, but I'm not sure that's what new objects that aren't assigned to any named variable should be called
```

Comment: that is fine. but i would avoid using a static state variable.

Comment: It is IDisposable abuse.  Yes, very hard to pass up.  But sooner or later you are going to run into a programmer that swears that disposing objects is optional and that it makes no sense whatsoever when the program is going to terminate a handful of milliseconds later anyway.  He's right of course.  Good luck explaining to him that you changed the contract.

Comment: @DanielA.White - Namely, `Level` variable? Surely however it ought to be okay and unsuspicious if I made entire `Report` class `static`, right? Or is it fishy code I should avoid?

Comment: i would avoid static for it all together.

Comment: @HansPassant - I enjoyed reading the "abuse" word there :) I only thought of this implementation as a way to delegate making sure I closed all brackets in proper places to runtime, while making it much more readible in the code (thanks to editor's brace indendation). Previously I meddled with `++Report.Indent` and `--Report.Indent` implementation which was all but predictable and intuitive ;)

Comment: What does the `Report.Indent()` method return?  Is that something that _should_ be disposed?  I don't see an anonymous object in that code, unless you mean a created object that is not assigned to a variable.

Comment: @HansPassant: Code which asks for an `IDisposable` to be created and then abandons it is broken unless the contract for the means of object creation expressly allows for abandonment.  Finalizers are a such lousy cleanup mechanism I think .NET would have been better off if the time spent on implementing finalizer-related data structure had been spent on other means of guarding against and handling resource leaks.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway - As in the P.S. I wrote in the original question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `using` enures that even "anonymous objects" are always disposed of.

Internally, `using` stores whatever value was used when entering the block in local variable. This stored value is disposed when exiting the block.

Comment: Can't stop loving determinism! ;)